# How to generate an xml file in C of 1GB

Tags: c

I don't know who to generate 1GB of data within a tag of XML.
I want to generate a line of data within the data text of 1GB of size
How can I realise this in the most efficient (speed-wise) way.
The data should be readable (can be nonsense of course)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf(" --- Creating XML");

    FILE *fptr;

    /*  open for writing */
    fptr = fopen("/tmp/emp.xml", "w");

    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
            printf("File does not exists \n");
            return 1;
    }


    fprintf(fptr, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n");
    fprintf(fptr, "<customer id=\"100\">\n");
    fprintf(fptr, "    <age>25</age>\n");
    fprintf(fptr, "    <name>New Customer</name>\n");
    fprintf(fptr, "    <data>dhgdhgdkrjgndliutghdnkljtghdliuthgdithugdnk...1GB_LONG<data>\n");
    fprintf(fptr, "</customer>");

    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: Just write "<foo>bar</foo>" in a loop a couple of million times?

Comment: How about a loop printing smaller chunks?

Comment: Maybe append until the 1st <data> tag and then insert random chars? and at the end finalise it with the rest of the tags? I'll have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating three files.

One with the xml until the opening of the tag in which the data should reside.
The second with the generated junk data.
The third with the close tag of the bulk data en the rest of the xml.

Like so:

```
   // Open two files to be merged
   FILE *fp1 = fopen("person1.xml", "r");
   FILE *fp2 = fopen("randomdata.txt", "r");
   FILE *fp3 = fopen("person3.xml", "r");


   // Open file to store the result
   FILE *fp4 = fopen("personf.xml", "w");
   char c;

   if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL || fp3 == NULL || fp4 == NULL)
   {
         puts(" --- Could not open files");
         exit(0);
   }

   // Copy contents of first file1
   while ((c = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF)
      fputc(c, fp4);

   printf(" --- Done copying file 1\n");
   // Copy contents of first file2
   while ((c = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF)
      fputc(c, fp4);

   printf(" --- Done copying file 2\n");

   // Copy contents of first file3
   while ((c = fgetc(fp3)) != EOF)
      fputc(c, fp4);

   printf(" --- Done copying file 3\n");

   printf("Merged files\n");

   fclose(fp1);
   fclose(fp2);
   fclose(fp3);
   fclose(fp4);
   return 0;
```